# Loading image from res folder

Tags: java, classpath, bufferedimage

Iam coding game as part of my homework and I'm trying to load a image from res folder but I'm getting NullPointerException:

````
```Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
at prg_hra/esrever.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(BufferedImageLoader.java:15)
at prg_hra/esrever.Hra.init(Hra.java:38)
at prg_hra/esrever.Hra.run(Hra.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)```
````

The res folder is already in **Java Build Path** and I'm 99% sure that I'm putting in the right path. I got BufferedImageLoader Class:

```
public class BufferedImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
```

and I'm using it in inti metode in game class:

```
private void init() {

    WIDTH=getWidth();
    HEIGHT=getHeight();

    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    level = loader.loadImage("/res/level.png");     

    handler = new Handler();

    kam=new Kamera(0,0);

    handler.addObjekt(new Hrac(100, 100, handler, ObjektID.Hrac));

    handler.createLevel();

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
}
```

I've looked at some similar problems of other people, but they mostly just used wrong path..

EDIT: I also tried 
`level = loader.loadImage("level.png");`
and 
`level = loader.loadImage("/level.png");`
neither worked.

Comment: Where is `"res/"` relative to your class path (at run time)? Without this information, there's no way to tell what the correct path is...

Answer (score 0):

Try that `level = loader.loadImage("level.png");` instead of `level = loader.loadImage("/res/level.png");`

If you are trying get resource you don't need to write resources directory.

Comment: I tried it, while also placing level.png to like every other folder in the code folder and still the same exception

Comment: Are you setted res directory as Resource folder in your IDE.

Comment: (Eclipse) You mean the properties -> Java build class -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder? yep I did that, but I had to click on either Module path or Classpath to be able to click on Add class folder

Comment: Probably, I didn't use Eclipse for a long time.